# less: Go to end of as much of the buffer as is loaded, not the actual end of the buffer

Tags: pipe, less

I'll often use `less` to page through the output of a program that's going to keep producing output, such as with `tail -f /var/log/messages | less`. Is it possible to jump to the bottom of the current buffer when doing this?

Normally when using `less` with a program that's expected to terminate (`grep <term> <files> | less`, for example), you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, and `less` will wait for the program to terminate and the pipe to close, then jump to the bottom of the buffer. However doing this with a pipe that will never terminate just causes `less` to hang.

Instead, I'd like `less` to just go to the bottom of whatever has already come through the pipe; is that possible?

Comment: Why not just use tail -f, there is a flag to let it sleep for a few seconds while producing output so your screen doesn't get too flooded?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728818/272449

Answer (score 4):

The first example you show can be trivially handled by `less` itself:

```
less /var/log/messages
```

and then hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> which puts `less` into "follow" mode, which translates roughly to `tail -f` functionality.

I suspect the `follow` mode is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ooh, nice, thank you! Is there a way to leave that mode again without leaving `less` entirely?

Comment: Hit ctrl-C which will cancel the "follow" mode.